# How to pause file m3u8 by libVLC in java/android?

Tags: java, android, libvlc, m3u8

I have a problem with file `m3u8`. I use `libVLC` to open the file. I can't pause video but I can stop it. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: is it a live stream? Some streams can't be paused

Comment: actually, I get links from sever. This is a Streamax m3u8 file. I can play, stop. But I can't pause it.

Comment: Yes so, is this a live stream?

Comment: No. It is a replay video